# ISearchJob->Release() stucking

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-update, wuapi

I'm using wuapi to find Windows Updates. I faced with the problem: *pJob->Release();* stucking in the following code on some machines, but generally it works correct. What could be the reason of such behavior?

I have tried to change *ISearchJob** to *CComPtr* and remove *pJob->Release();*, but issue isn't gone. In this case program stucks on the end of the function.

```
        ISearchResult* pWUResult = NULL;
        ISearchJob* pJob = NULL;
        VARIANT pVar = { 0 };
        ISCC completeCB;
        hr = pWUSearcher->BeginSearch( bstrCriteria, &completeCB, pVar, &pJob );

        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            WaitForSingleObject( completeCB._Event, INFINITE );

            hr = pWUSearcher->EndSearch( pJob, &pWUResult );
            pJob->Release();
        }
```

Comment: Are you initializing all threads that use COM into the correct COM apartment? Do all of your apartment-threaded threads dispatch messages? As an aside, changing `ISearchJob*` to `CComPtr` doesn't remove the call to `Release`. It just hides it in the source code.

Comment: what you mean under `Release()` *stucking* ? it hung and not return ? and you detect that exactly `Release()` hung ?

Comment: @RbMm, I have added a lot of logs before and after it. Yep, I mean that it hung and not return.
@IInspectable, I initialize COM like this `hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (void**)&pWUSession);` in the thread, which contains the previous code.

Comment: You initialize a thread into a COM apartment by calling [CoInitializeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex). Make sure you read and understand [Why does CoCreateInstance work even though my thread never called CoInitialize? The curse of the implicit MTA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613).

Comment: @IInspectable, Yep, sorry. The thread has an implicit MTA apartment type. One of the threads initialized with `::CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);`, but no one thread call `Co­Initialize­[Ex]`.
Also it's works in general, but it doesn't work one one machine.

Comment: If it reproducibly fails on one machine, pull a minidump (using Task Manager, for example), and use that to investigate, where (and ultimately, why) the call hangs. [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg) is probably your best friend when debugging deadlocks.

Comment: Does it help if you call `pJob->CleanUp()` before releasing it?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I will try, thanks!

Comment: @IInspectable ok, I will also try investigate minidump, thanks!

Comment: @Zhenya Has this issue been solved?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFTSorry for the long delay. Yes, it was resolved by calling pJob->CleanUp() instead if pJob->Realise().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JonathanPotter suggested in comments, using pJob->CleanUp() instead of pJob->Release() was resolved the issue.